# RedHat Redis Cluster port permission trouble

Tags: linux, redis, permissions, redhat, rhel

I am running into a problem trying to create a redis cluster following the instructions outlined here:
https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

The error I am getting in the logs when calling `sudo service redis start`:

/etc/log/redis/redis.log:

`3432:M 04 Aug 13:38:57.411 * Node configuration loaded, I'm 7442dbd9342231844b12ede7513470c092bd4646
3432:M 04 Aug 13:38:57.411 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:16379: bind: Permission denied`

Interestingly enough when I start service using sudo with the same configuration file the service starts as expected according to the redis.log file:

command copied from the service script: `sudo /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf`:

`3484:M 04 Aug 13:59:14.900 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
3484:M 04 Aug 13:59:14.900 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379`

From what I know it seems like a permission issue, but I am failing to understand or to find out where there is such thing as user/usergroup -> port binding permissions. The same service is able to bind the redis port 6379 but unable to bind port 16379.

Any suggestions/thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Florian, it was indeed SELinux blocking access to port 16379 for redis process.

The article that lead to the answer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/566317/nginx-no-permission-to-bind-port-8090-but-it-binds-to-80-and-8080

The gist to install redis on RedHat in cluster mode to spare the nightmare for others:
https://gist.github.com/vkhazin/f5c1b6e36e3a6c29aaf882041aaf78cb